# Custom Headers for OAuthSwift

Tags: swift, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am using OAuthSwift to authenticate a user, but I already have the user's credentials stored in a cookie, and I need to set the cookie as the headers of my OAuthSwift instance before attempting to authorize.

I know you can change the `OAuthSwiftCredential.authorizationHeader` but what about adding my own set of headers? Is this even possible?

```
oauth = OAuth2Swift(consumerKey: ""...)

// Change oauth headers here>

oauth.authorize(withCallbackURL: ""...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/ 1. Build authorization header string

```
let auth = OAuthSwiftClient.authorizationHeaderForMethod(method.rawValue,
    url: URLWithPath,
    parameters: parameters!,
    credential: Semantics3Router.oauthClient.credential)
```

// 2. Make URL request

```
let URLRequest = OAuthRequestBuilder.makeRequest(URLWithPath,
    method: method.rawValue,
    headers: [ "Authorization" : auth ],
    parameters: parameters!,
    dataEncoding: dataEncoding)
```

Comment: did this help you?

Comment: No.. `authorizationHeaderForMethod` is not a function of *OAuthSwiftClient*. and *OAuthRequestBuilder* is not anything.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out headers is actually built into the `authorize` function as an optional. I just didn't see it until I was looking in the source code.

```
open func authorize(withCallbackURL callbackURL: URL, scope: String, 
    state: String, parameters: Parameters = [:], headers: 
    OAuthSwift.Headers? = nil, success: @escaping TokenSuccessHandler, 
    failure: FailureHandler?) -> OAuthSwiftRequestHandle?
```

Xcode use to display the optionals for the autofill options, I wonder why it doesn't do that anymore??